# Arrange data in specific order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table that contain 8 records. I want to arrange the data in descending order on the basis of field **id** (that is a primary key of that table) but except id 3 and 5. So eventually the result should be like

```
id  name
--  ----
3   peter
5   david
8   john
7   stella
6   jim
4   jack
2   nancy
1   scott
```

Except id 3 and 5 rest of the data should be arranged in descending order and 3 and 5 should come in ascending order.

Comment: +1 for the question as well :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something like this:

```
order by 
   case 
     when id = 3 then 999
     when id = 5 then 998
     else id
   end desc
```

This assumes that you really don't have more than 8 rows. Otherwise you must change the "magic" numbers that move 3 and 5 to the top.

Comment: hmm.. So if that user exceeds then in that case your query will not work?

Comment: @sureyn: you could simply increase the `999` to a really big value.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY IF(id=3 OR id=5, id, ~id) ASC
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: execute the query SELECT IF(id=3 OR id=5, id, ~id) FROM user and you will get the answer

Comment: It gives strange numbers. What are they?

Comment: they are temporary auto generate numbers regardless of taking care of number of records in a table.

Comment: It is very well similar to this 
`SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY IF(id=3 OR id=5, id, id-8) desc` But here you need to define the number to the max id ;)
;

Comment: That's right. but we don't want to bother about the max id. :)

Comment: This worked better for me. SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY case 
                            when id = 3 then 0
                            when id = 5 then -1
                            else id
                        end ASC

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick here is to use an enum.

```
SELECT id, name FROM my_table WHERE id IN (3, 5) ORDER BY ASC
UNION
SELECT id, name FROM my_table WHERE id NOT IN(3, 5) ORDER BY DESC
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using UNION?

Comment: By the SQL standard you are not able to order parts of a UNION. Does MySQL allow this nevertheless? And is the order retained even though MySQL will try to remove duplicates between the two parts?

Comment: My bad. I guess I made assumptions on the standard.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, there is a function called `FIELD` which *returns zero if a value is not found on the list` eg,

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 5, 3) DESC, id DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b93a1/5)
- [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Comment: But that return the id like 3,5,1,2,4,6 and so on... Where as output should come like 3,5,8,7,6,4....